# List<T> values inside lock erased after lock

Tags: c#, thread-safety, locking

I'm currently trying to create a cache manager but whenever I execute AddElementToCache no values are saved to the List.

I have managed to debug and I have seen that every time it exits the lock the recently added value gets erased.

Below you can find my CacheManager class and its methods:

```
public class CacheManager<T>
{
    public CacheManagerConfiguration CacheManagerConfiguration;
    private static List<T> _cachedElements;
    private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim _lock;


    public CacheManager(CacheManagerConfiguration configuration)
    {
        CacheManagerConfiguration = configuration;

        _lock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

        if (_cachedElements == null)
        {
            _cachedElements = new List<T>();
        }
    }

    public void AddElementToCache(T element)
    {
        _lock.EnterWriteLock();

        try
        {
            _cachedElements.Add(element);
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can run this in a unit test, add an item, and it gets added. The mixed use of instance and static members is problematic. I recommend not making any of this static. But still, I'm curious about why it would appear to delete items. Can you post an example of how you're interacting with it? I can guess but I think seeing the client code will clear it up.

Comment: @Orace derp. Short reaction: lots of minor yet consequential issues with the code. You might want to just use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: What you're seeing is probably due to this not being thread safe. First off you use a static list (shared among all instances of this class which share the same type T) but the lock is not static, so multiple instances of this class can still write to the list at the same time. Same goes with the constructor, there's no thread safety here either. you want only 1 thread at the same time executing the complete `if (_cachedElements == null) _cachedElements = new List<T>();`.

Comment: @ScottHannen there is no need for context, it is pretty hard to explain. But just to let you know, if i erase lock statement it saves all elements without any problem.

Comment: @Knoop changed list to non static and same behavior.

Comment: @Marcelo can you show the code where you create the CacheManager and where you call the AddElementToCache? if I make the list non static and test it like this: `var test = new CacheManager<int>();

            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                var val = i;
                Task.Run(() =>
                    test.AddElement(val)
                );
            }` it works fine for me (I end up with a list of 100 int's that are not sorted)

Comment: @Knoop `var cacheManager = new CacheManager<CashTransactionCacheItem>(cacheConfiguration);

            DispatchManager.RegisterItemFilter<IMTransaction>(t => 
            {
                
                if (!cacheManager.Exists(t))
                {
                    cacheManager.AddElementToCache(t);
                }
            });`

Comment: @Knoop needless to say that cahchemanager also has a function called Exists which is the next detailed : `public bool Exists(T element)
        {
           _lock.EnterReadLock();

        try
        {
            return _cachedElements.Contains(element);
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.ExitReadLock();
        }
        }`

Comment: @Marcelo and what does this Dispatchmanager.RegisterItemFilter do exactly? And when is the code that creates a new CacheManager called (keep in mind that everytime a new CacheManager is created it starts with an empty List)

Comment: @Knoop I know but it is extremelly strange that whenever the service goes out of lock it erases all records inside _cachedElements

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186061/discussion-between-knoop-and-marcelo).